# Size of object of derived class

Tags: java

When we have two classes in Java, one inheriting from the other, will the object of the derived class take up space equivalent to data members in the base class plus the members of derived class itself?

Comment: Sure yes, of course bro

Comment: why not? any explanation

Comment: What exactly are you asking and why?  It sounds like you're asking if data values take up space in memory.  They do, yes.  But surely that's *obvious* and there's something else you're *trying* to ask?

Comment: @David, AutomatedOwl cleared my doubt. The way he's answered is pretty much what was looking for.

Comment: Except for the thing that his answer is wrong. The memory requirements for a class are known before the ctor is invoked. The JVM first allocates the memory, then the ctor is invoked (and can do its job and assign values). And yes, the simple answer is: of course the instance of a derived class comes with the memory required for any super class field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory requirements for a class are known before the constructor is invoked. The JVM first allocates the memory for the fileds in the declared class and all of its deriving classes, then the constructor is invoked. For filling the object values and methods, it's all about the [Stack and the Heap](https://www.journaldev.com/4098/java-heap-space-vs-stack-memory).

Once ObjectB is inheriting ObjectA, he is calling ObjectA super method (constructor):

```
class ObjectB extends ObjectA {
    public ObjectB() {
      super();
    }
}
```

Then, your Java program would call the ObjectA constructor and initialize its own methods:

```
class ObjectA {
    public ObjectB() {
      // Some code
    }
}
```

So in every line that would contain an initialization, the data would be written to the heap, therefore filling another pre-required memory in the size of each initialized inner object. Take into account that ObjectA would also inherit from ['Object' class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), as by definition  it's a must by every Java object, even if you don't the call 'super()' method by yourself, it would be done behind the scenes.

Comment: Huh? What nonsense. The memory requirements for an object are known **prior** to the ctor being invoked. The init sequence doesn't create any memory, it just assigns values to previously empty / defaulted slots.